# llenar un datatable con ajax y php mvc

Tags: php, mvc, ms-access, datatable

Hola estoy tratando de llenar un datatable en php pero no logro hacerlo, esto es lo que tengo:

**controlador**

```
public function VentasXvendedor(){

        $IdVendedor= strtoupper(utf8_encode($_REQUEST['IdVendedor']));
         $arrayCli=array();
        $data=$this->model->BuscarVentasXvendedor($IdVendedor);
        for ($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++) {               
            $resultadodetallado_json = array(               
                'c_numped'      => utf8_encode($data[$i]->c_numped),//
                'c_nomcli'      => utf8_encode($data[$i]->c_nomcli),//
                'c_asunto'      => utf8_encode($data[$i]->c_asunto),
                'c_login'       => utf8_encode($data[$i]->c_login),
                'estado'        => utf8_encode($data[$i]->estado),
                'moneda'        => utf8_encode($data[$i]->moneda),
                'd_fecped'      => utf8_encode($data[$i]->d_fecped),
                'n_tcamb'       => utf8_encode($data[$i]->n_tcamb),
                'total'         => utf8_encode($data[$i]->total)
             );     

         array_push($arrayCli, $resultadodetallado_json);        
        } 
        echo(json_encode($arrayCli));  

    }
```

**Modelo**

```
public function BuscarVentasXvendedor($ivendedor)
    {
        try
        {
            $variable=trim($ivendedor);
            $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT sum_detalle.c_numped, sum_detalle.c_tipped, sum_detalle.d_fecped, sum_detalle.c_codcli, sum_detalle.c_nomcli, sum_detalle.c_asunto, Sum(sum_detalle.n_preprd) AS total, sum_detalle.n_tcamb, sum_detalle.moneda, sum_detalle.c_estado, sum_detalle.n_swtapr, sum_detalle.n_preapb, sum_detalle.b_IncIgv, sum_detalle.n_apbpre, sum_detalle.c_login, IIf(pedicab.c_estado='0' And pedicab.n_swtapr=1,'Aprobado',IIf(pedicab.c_estado='0' And pedicab.n_swtapr=0 ,'Generado',IIf((pedicab.c_estado='2' or pedicab.c_estado='1' ) And pedicab.n_swtapr=1,'Facturado',IIf(pedicab.c_estado='4' And pedicab.n_swtapr=0,'Eliminado',IIf(pedicab.c_estado='5' And pedicab.n_swtapr=1,'Fusionado','nada'))))) AS estado
                FROM sum_detalle
                where sum_detalle.c_login='$variable'
                GROUP BY sum_detalle.c_numped, sum_detalle.c_tipped, sum_detalle.d_fecped, sum_detalle.c_codcli, sum_detalle.c_nomcli, sum_detalle.c_asunto, sum_detalle.n_tcamb, sum_detalle.moneda, sum_detalle.c_estado, sum_detalle.n_swtapr, sum_detalle.n_preapb, sum_detalle.b_IncIgv, sum_detalle.n_apbpre, sum_detalle.c_login;
                ");
            $stm->execute();
            return $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Vista**

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label>Vendedor</label>
                <select id="vendedores" name="vendedores" class="form-control select2">
                  <option selected="selected">Seleccione</option>
                    <?php foreach($this->model->ListarVendedores() as $vendedores):
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $vendedores->c_login; ?>"
                        > 
                        <?php echo $vendedores->c_nombre; ?> </option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <option selected="TODOS">TODOS</option>
                </select>
              </div>
<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Cotizacion</th>
            <th>Cliente</th>
            <th>Asunto</th>
            <th>Vendedor</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Moneda</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>T. Cambio</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jquery (esta dentro de la vista)**
Aqui es donde necesito saber como llamar  a la funcion para poder llenar mi datatable

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#vendedores').on('change', function() {  

$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {
    "url": "?c=dashboard&a=VentasXvendedor",
    "data": function ( d ) {
        d.IdVendedor = $('#vendedores').val();
    }
  }
} );

 })
})
```

me marca este error:

> TypeError: f is undefined[Saber más]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Buen día espero que esto se ha de tu ayuda....***

### Controlador

```
public  function VentasXvendedor() {
$data = array();
$IdVendedor = strtoupper(utf8_encode($_REQUEST['IdVendedor']));
$arrayCli = array();
$data = $this->model->BuscarVentasXvendedor($IdVendedor);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    $resultadodetallado = array();
    array_push($resultadodetallado, utf8_encode($data[$i]->c_numped));
    array_push($resultadodetallado, utf8_encode($data[$i]->c_nomcli));
    array_push($resultadodetallado, utf8_encode($data[$i]->c_asunto));
    array_push($resultadodetallado, utf8_encode($data[$i]->c_login));
    array_push($resultadodetallado, utf8_encode($data[$i]->estado));
    array_push($resultadodetallado, utf8_encode($data[$i]->moneda));
    array_push($resultadodetallado, utf8_encode($data[$i]->d_fecped));
    array_push($resultadodetallado, utf8_encode($data[$i]->n_tcamb));
    array_push($resultadodetallado, utf8_encode($data[$i]->total));
    $arrayCli['data'][] = $resultadodetallado;
}
echo(json_encode($arrayCli));
```

}

### Vista Jquery

```
    var url="";
    $('#example').dataTable({
    ajax:url,
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ],
    "bDestroy": true,
    "autoWidth": false,
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    destroy: true
});
```

Comment: Gracias, con eso si me esta cargando los datos en la tabla, solo tengo otro inconveniente, que es que al momento de cambiar el combo (que es el que hace que la tabla se llene) me aparece esta alerta "DataTables warning: table id=example - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3"

Comment: Hola @VanesaClaros, ese error del datatables se da cuando en una o unas filas hay mas celdas que en el resto, solo debes verificar que el numero de celdas sea igual en todas las filas, luego esto no afecta en ninguna forma a la vista, es solo una alerta.

Comment: Revisa a el siguiente enlace:https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3

Comment: ok muchas  gracias ... Lo revisare...

Comment: Hola Antonio Josue ...Tengo otro error (TypeError: f is undefined), cuando se hace la consulta y no encuentra ningun dato, deberia aparecer la tabla vacia, con la descripcion dentro de la tabla: "no hay registros ".. como podria hacer eso?

Comment: Hola Vanesa, has una decisión que si la variable $data tiene registros haga tu ciclo for si no has esto         $arrayCli['data'][] = ["", "", "", "", "","", "", "", "", ""];

Comment: Gracias por contestar @AntonioJosue, con eso, ya no aparece ningun dato, pero tampoco aparece la cabecera de la tabla, , me podrias ayudar con eso, y neceseito que salga la tabla vacia con la descripcion que no hay registros, Gracias